# PDF with LaTeX formulas to .epub format

Tags: environments, pdf, conversion, epub

I have recently purchased a Kobo e-reader, and apart from standard .epub books I have already imported (which work excellently) I would also like to use it to read some .pdf files that also contain LaTeX. Unfortunately the screen is too small to allow me to read most of them comfortably directly in this format, so I need to convert them to .epub or similar formats in order to be able to change font size on the e-reader.

Is there a reliable way to do this (with Calibre or some other software) that doesn't mess up page layouts and the size of formulas inside environments? (I have already seen questions asked about converting from .tex to .epub, but nothing about pre-compiled PDFs).

Comment: I would be rather confident that the answer to this is that there is no way to achieve this (reliably). You'd essentially have to have a program that actually _understands_ what it sees in the PDF in order to be able to create the associated .epub format...

Comment: @Raven I understand. The main problem I have found is that even with some electronic textbooks I own, all LaTeX that is not inline is shrunk to a ridiculously small and unreadable font size on the device. However I am now experimenting with a couple of workarounds that may work for me (simple landscape mode or the conversion tool k2pdfopt).

Comment: Yeah I absolutely see why this would be a neat thing to do (so if you find a solution that'd be great). But I am afraid that there (currently) is none available...